# Can machines of finite size ever solve their own halting problems?

Tags: computability, halting-problem

A real-life computer can only store programs and inputs up to a certain length, which means that its halting problem can be solved with a lookup table. The most obvious way to represent this table grows exponentially with the number of bits in the computer's state description, and so wouldn't fit inside the memory of the computer that it was answering the question about. Aside from trivial cases, are there finite computer-like machines that can answer their own halting problems?

Comment: do all finite state machines count as trivial cases? Also, pushdown automata? Others with runtime bounded by input size?

Comment: @JohnDvorak (Minor point: allowing $\epsilon$ transitions loops would make those cases less trivial, since termination is no longer guaranteed. I think we need to disallow these.)